# MVC 3 razor, syntax error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, syntax

How can I avoid the next logic ? I have the next code in view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var x = $("#myId1").val();
    @if(Model.IsOptions)
    {
     $('#myId2').click(function () { doSomething(); });
    }
</script>
```

So, I want execute $('#myId2').. only if 'Model.IsOption' is true. Currently Visual Studio underline it as wrong code.

Comment: what is the datatype of Model.IsOptions?, it is Boolean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code inside @if should be C#, not JavaScript. Razor tries to execute it on server, not on client. To force it to treat it as JavaScript, you should use `<text></text>` or `@:`, like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = $("#myId1").val();
    @if(Model.IsOptions)
    {
        <text>
            $('#myId2').click(function () { doSomething(); });
        </text>
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
@{
    if(Model.IsOptions)
    {
         $('#myId2').click(function () { doSomething(); });
    }
}
```

Does it work?